# sharedpreferences - getInt only when first button is clicked

Tags: android, button, onclick, sharedpreferences

***scenario*** during a ball game i click exit and return to the main menu and then exit out of the app, once I launch the app again I can click 'Continue" from the main menu and return to the game where i had left off or click New game and start again fresh.

***problem*** the sharedpreferences code works when i delete the onclick method however i only want it to work when i click 'continue' otherwise it would read it regardless of what button is pressed from the main menu.

How do i get it to read getshared preferences from the continue button only and start new game ignoring shared preferences when i click new game button.

for example.

```
public class GMActivity extends Activity {

Button conButton;
Button nButton;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    conButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ConGame);
    nButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NGame);


    // Continue Button
    conButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle setting = getIntent().getBundleExtra("setting");
            Intent newIntent = new Intent(GMaActivity.this,
                    GActivity.class);
            newIntent.putExtra("setting", setting);
            startActivity(newIntent);


        }
    });

    // New Game Button
    nButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(GMActivity.this,
                            GActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

---

```
 public class GActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


  private int RWIDTH = 70;
// + a whole bunch of other unrelated stuff that i cut-out to make viewing easier. 

public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.main);
Button CntButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ConGame);
CntButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    RWIDTH = settings.getInt("RWIDTH", RWIDTH);

  }
});


}

 protected void onStop(){
  super.onStop();

SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

editor.putInt("RWIDTH", RWIDTH);

editor.commit();


}
```

Comment: What have you done with the OnClickListener on the "New Game" button?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(GMActivity.this, GActivity.class); the new game button pretty much just starts a new game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a boolean flag to set whether the `RWIDTH` should be used in the game activity like this:

```
conButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Bundle setting = getIntent().getBundleExtra("setting");
        Intent newIntent = new Intent(GMaActivity.this,
                GActivity.class);
        newIntent.putExtra("useRWIDTH", true);
        startActivity(newIntent);

    }
});

// New Game Button
nButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(GMActivity.this,
                        GActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("useRWIDTH", false);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Then in the GMaActivity class use

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
boolean useRWIDTH = intent.getBooleanExtra("useRWIDTH", false);
```

Then according to the value of useRWIDTH you can choose to use or not to use the RWIDTH value from the `SharedPreferences`

Comment: could you please expand the last part, would -- if (useRWIDTH) { SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    RWIDTH = settings.getInt("RWIDTH", RWIDTH); } work?

Comment: Yes ofcourse! But I think it would be better if you avoided declaring the SharedPreferences variable inside the if block and somewhere in the onCreate() or even in onResume().

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extra boolean flag to continue or newgame depending on the button click. Post full code if you need more clarification

Comment: I edited the OP with more code, I was thinking about doing something like that but not quite sure how to execute it

Comment: well, would i get rid of the onClick that reads the preferences when i click 'continue'. the issue is that it doesn't register the onClick method, so do i replace that with an if statement?